# Fire on return from form "Submit"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I want to be able to parse values on return from a submit post. I can't seem to find a way to do this without manually initiating an ajax call through javascript

Code on webpage:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/formSubmit" >
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Code on nodejs server:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("HERE: " + req.body.username);
    console.log("HERE: " + req.body.email);
    res.json({ data1: 'Hello', data2: 'World'});
}
```

EDIT #1: Currently this just renders "{ data1: 'Hello', data2: 'World'}" into the browser, but I need to parse it

Comment: your html form `action="/formSubmit"` is has no route in the code you provided. Change the route on the server. `router.post("/formSubmit", fun...`

Comment: @magreenberg I have it in my app.js:  var users = require('./routes/formSubmit'); app.use('/formSubmit', formSubmit);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to see after the form submit? The way you handle the POST request you're sending a JSON. So you would indeed need AJAX to render your result more beautiful. In order to avoid the usage of AJAX you just have to send the response as HTML file.

Of course you can also pass the submitted form data to a template and send it to the user. Pass the variables you need to your template:

```
res.render('formsubmit', {data1: 'Hello', data2: 'World'});
```

for that you would need to have a template file in your template directory called `formsubmit` (plus the file ending depending on your view engine) which takes the given variables. Express will take care of creating a HTML file out of it.

E.g. for Handlebars you can access the variables in the template file named `formsubmit.hbs` in your views folder like:

```
<p>Hello, my name is {{data}} and not {{data2}}.
```

See also: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Could you show me how to access the data from the template?

Comment: Which template engine are you using? What's the exact Node.js module's name? there are different ones

Comment: @Henry I updated my answer for how to use it with Handlebars (as you tagged it in your question. Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow